# why i cannot await 'System.Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I have the following repository method:-

```
  public  IQueryable<TSet> getAllScanEmailTo()
        {
         return   t.TSets.Where(a=>a.Name.StartsWith("ScanEmail"));

        }
```

which is being called as follow:-

```
var emailsTo = repository.getAllScanEmailTo().ToList();
```

now i tried to change the above to be using async so i modifed my repository method to be as follow:-

```
 public async Task<  IQueryable<TSet>> getAllScanEmailTo()
        {
         return  await t.TSets.Where(a=>a.Name.StartsWith("ScanEmail"));

        }
```

but i got the following error :-

```
Error   1   Cannot await 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Final.Models.TSet>'
```

Comment: Why did you expect it to work?  `IQueryable` is not an awaitable, like a task.

Comment: `IQueryable` is a *query*, not an operation, asynchronous or otherwise. `ToList` or `ToListAsync` are the operations. Apart from that, you can only use `await` on methods that return `Task` or an awaiter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but i am unable to change my repository method  to be a Task as i will get the error mentioned above ..

Comment: Are you sure you want to use await, because Await is used to Mimic none Async functionality with out locking the primary execution thread, so normally your entire GUI would lock up while you waited for the query to run, which your IQueryable wont do until Enumerated, with await your GUI works normaly until the await returns then runs the rest of the function

Comment: @MikeT i did not get your point .. please review ur reply,, it is confusing ..

Comment: @sstan so how i should re-write it ?

Comment: Why did this question has 3 downvotes ? it looks like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you mentioned you are using EF6, you can use `.ToListAsync()`. Then you can `await` on that.

Comment: yes i am using EF 6 ,,, but the problem is that i can not apply .ToListAsync() on the following "repository.getAllScanEmailTo().ToListAsync();"  because i will get an error that IQuerable does not contain a definition for ToListAsync()

Comment: @johnG ensure your `using` namespaces are setup properly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx

Comment: yes my using namespaces are set correctly as i have other method that i can define .Tolistasync() on it ,, could the problem be is that i can not use async with .where ?

Comment: @johnG please expand your question or better yet ask a new one. comments aren't a good place to put coe.

Comment: i do no think it is related to MailMessage as this will happen even outside the MailMessage.. so now i am return back to my original question , how i can define .tolistasync() over IQuerable ?

Comment: @johnG entity framework 6 has built in support for that see the link i gave you earlier.

Comment: yes i know this and i am using ToListAsync() on many other methods ,, but for this one i am unable to define ToListAsync() and i am getting this error  "Error   1   Cannot await 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Final.Models.TSet>'"

Comment: ok i added the following using statement "using System.Data.Entity;" and it is working well now , actually i can reference ToListAsync() now .. not sure why i can not use ToListAsync() unless i define "using System.Data.Entity;"?? while i can use ToList() even without "using System.Data.Entity;"??

Comment: This is all explained in the link Daniel provided you (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx): *"The `using` statement for the `System.Data.Entity` namespace gives us access to the EF async extension methods."*